# Topbar dropdown went to Hot Questions instead of showing my list of sites

Tags: bug, status-completed

Clicked on the StackExchange dropdown to navigate to another site, and...

[image: The unexpected landing point after using the StackExchange dropdown on the Topbar]

From other pages (in another tab) the behaviour is normal.

Then I noticed the url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725199/trim-functions-in-cobol/26777329?noredirect=1#comment42135785_26777329`

Using that url, for me, it is repeatable.

I had the question in a tab, had typed a comment into the answer box(!), then added it as a comment on an answer and submitted. A few minutes later I refreshed the tab, to see if the answer had been edited. It had instead been deleted. I had perhaps viewed the answerer's profile in between making the comment and doing the refresh.

Perhaps not easy to reproduce, and, if this is the only example, not very important.

Comment: You may have clicked it before JavaScript had a chance to register the on click event (or for some reason JavaScript didn't execute/load). In markup the logo/drop down is a link to se.com

Comment: I'm faster than JavaScript? I did try to recreate on other tabs starting from the question. I was disappointed that the answer had been deleted, so there was a pause. However, thinking now, I may have clicked *harder* than usual. Double-click with very short interval?

Comment: Nope. Can't get anywhere with that.

Comment: could have been some network blip too...

Comment: When I paste this to the end of a url, the effect occurs `?noredirect=1#comment42135785_26777329`. Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this. Doctor - so stop doing that, then.

Comment: Perhaps it was within five minutes of posting the comment, which was no longer there, but in the url even after the refresh?

Comment: I can't repro either - even with the fragment identifier at the end of the url.

Comment: OK, just a curiosity then. Even clearing my browser cache (Firefox 33.0, Ubuntu canon stuff) I can paste that on to any question I choose at random and it happens. On SO and MSO.

Comment: @Oded I've just tried from a different machine. Pasting `?noredirect=1#comment42135785_26777329` to the end of the url of this question causes the effect. For me.

Comment: Is that comment link on the same post? Or a comment on a different post?

Comment: @Oded The comment link is from the original question, the comment was deleted along with the answer. So for me the comment doesn't exist anymore. For someone with more power...

Comment: But when I paste it (exactly the same) to any random question, the same thing happens.

Comment: Ah. That may be a good part of the issue. If the comment fragment isn't on that page.

Comment: @Oded OK. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Yeah. Confirmed - in Windows 7, latest Chrome and FF 33.02 (though probably across the board)

Comment: That kills the JS on the page - you can see an error in the console. Looking at a fix.

Comment: @Oded Excellent. Speedy work. Thanks again.

Comment: Though this is a fairly rare condition - requires a link to a comment that is no longer there ;)

Comment: @Oded Well, rare if it depends on the answer being deleted to get rid of the comment (my situation). Perhaps not so rare if it is just a comment deleted while someone happens to be on the page (and refreshes). I didn't see "a change has been made to this of some time" kind of message (not done for an answer deleted - "the is one fewer answers to this question" or something). If just deleting comment, less rare. Has the code changed recently I guess is the answer as to whether it is worth a fix :-)

Comment: Yeah, not sure if I have an answer for you... the code that deals with comments is tricky, figuring out a fix that doesn't break 10 other use cases... well.

Comment: @Oded That sounds like a consensus for "low priority" and use this Q as a duplicate for future reports.

Comment: Guess it is low priority. Still, looking at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was easier to fix than I initially thought.

The (corner?) case here was only that of hitting a comment link to a post that has since been deleted.

I've added a guard clause against that, and JS (including the sites dropdown) shouldn't break under these conditions.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.11.6.1996, meta rev 2014.11.6.2728).